# How to use detected objectes from tensorflow object detection api using mobilenet for object tracking?

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, object-detection-api, video-tracking

I have trained the object detection API for custom object detection. Now I want to track the objects detected by the API.

Comment: Typically the object detection model gives you the bounding box of the detected object. You can use that to track objects, the problem is to identify if detected object across multiple inferences is the same object, you may use bounding box size but the solution depends on the use case.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at SORT algorithm. It is contains:

- Kalman filter for prediction of new position
- Hungurian algorithm for track and detections matching with IOU distance (or you can write your own criteria)

Above it you can attack any logic that you want. This links might be interesting:

- [Deep SORT](https://github.com/nwojke/deep_sort) - for each detection it build descriptor for image area. This descriptor compares with track descriptors
- [SORT](https://github.com/knorth55/chainer-sort) - simple SORT with FasterRCNN and SSD detection

In our projects we adapt SORT to use template matching between detections. If performance crucial for you, this is also might be good idea to think about.